# linq query selecting all elements of certain value but none of another value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks somewhat like this:

```
| FruitID | BasketID | FruitType |
```

I'm passing in the query a list of `BasketIDs` and I want the list of `FruitIDs` that are within the `BasketID` AND that are only of a certain `FruitType` (values can only 1 or 2).

This is what I have:

```
var TheQuery = (from a in MyDC.MyTable

                where TheBasketIDs.Contains(a.BasketID) &&
                      a.FruitType == 1 // need help here

                select a.FruitID).ToList();
```

I'm having some difficulty expressing the second `where` condition. I want the `FruitIDs` where all the `FruitType` are all 1s and none are 2s.

```
| FruitID | BasketID | FruitType |
|   23    |    2     |    1      |
|   23    |    5     |    1      |  
|   19    |    2     |    1      |
|   19    |    5     |    2      |
```

For instance, Fruit 23 is ok because its `FruitType` is always 1 but Fruit 19 isn't ok because it also has a `FruitType` of 2, even if the list of `TheBasketIDs` I'm passing in doesn't contain a 5.

Comment: Which LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @svick: yes, linq-to-sql; for now.

Comment: So - FruitID is not unique in the table.  A Fruit has a different type depending on which basket it is in...  details details.

Comment: @DavidB: yes, a FruitID can be in the table multiple times (it's not the primary key).

Comment: What if I replace line 2 of your example, `{23,5,1}` with `{23,5,3}`? Should it make it into the output?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: no, Type is only 1 or 2 but never 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this would be to group by fruit id, and then examine the resultant groups with LINQ expressions:

```
var ids = MyDC.MyTable
    .GroupBy(r => r.FruitID)
    // The following condition examines g, the group of rows with identical FruitID:
    .Where(g => g.Any(item => TheBasketIDs.Contains(item.BasketID))
             && g.Any(item => item.FruitType == 1)
             && g.All(item => item.FruitType != 2))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

This produces the list of `FruitID`s of your desired type.

**EDIT:** (in response to a comment below)

> Type is only 1 or 2 but never 3

Then you can simplify your query as follows:

```
var ids = MyDC.MyTable
    .GroupBy(r => r.FruitID)
    // The following condition examines g, the group of rows with identical FruitID:
    .Where(g => g.Any(item => TheBasketIDs.Contains(item.BasketID))
              // When there is no 3-rd state, FruitType==1 will keep FruitType==2 out
             && g.All(item => item.FruitType == 1))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Shouldn't I first group by all the BasketIDs in the list passed in? There are going to be millions of FruitIDs in the table.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Sry, I think his thread was updated. I deleted the comment.

Comment: @frenchie I think you meant "filter", not "group" by `BasketID`. If you do that, the logic will no longer "see" the `FruitType==2` items if they are in one of the baskets that you filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

```
var TheQuery = (from a in MyDC.MyTable
                group a by a.FruitID into g
                where g.Any(b => TheBasketIDs.Contains(b.BasketID)) && g.All(b => b.FruitType == 1)
                select g.Key).ToList();
```